# Javascript: change based on whether IE7 or not

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, conditional-compilation

I would like to change a line of my javascript code based on whether the browser is IE7 or not. Here is the code for any other browser:

```
function showHint(myId) 
{
    document.getElementById(myId).style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

For IE7, I want display = "inline".

I've made an attempt at conditional compilation ([this](http://gmatter.wordpress.com/2006/11/21/another-way-to-detect-ie7-in-javascript/) showed me how to detect the browser), but it didn't work:

```
function showHint(myId) 
        {
            document.getElementById(myId).style.display = "inline-block";
            /*@cc_on
                @if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf(“MSIE 7.”)!=-1)
                {
                    document.getElementById(myId).style.display = "inline";
                }
            @*/
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I'm not using JQuery.

Comment: Why would you need this? User Agent sniffing is a bad approach if what you are really after is **feature detection** http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting

Comment: Is your question "Why do you need to display "inline" instead of "inline-block"? Because in IE7 "inline-block" shows a line beneath the element, and "inline" doesn't.

Comment: What is the doctype? Is the page rendered in standards mode or quirksmode? Have you validated it in http://validator.w3.org/ ?

Comment: Jeff Meatball Yang's answer is the best, as it's the only one that can't be fooled by the browser (unless some other browser comes along and starts supporting IE's conditional comments, but that's pretty unlikely). Another approach would be to toggle `className`s, and set your styles in CSS (better separation of concerns).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a global determined by the behavior of IE's [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(VS.85).aspx) parsing:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><script> var isIE7 = true; </script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `navigator.userAgent`.

If you use jQuery, you can simply write

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version === 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use regular expression to determine MSIE 7:

```
if(/MSIE 7/.test(navigator.appVersion)) { /* msie7 related code */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jquery Plugin detecting the Browser Version. I do not know the exact Link ...

Answer (score 0):

Conditional compilation should work. It seems that your error is that you are using fancy quotes to delimit a string (`“MSIE 7.”`) or that you are attempting to assign display to something unknown to IE and it is having a fit over it and throwing an error. Here is a more concise version of the function that doesn't repeat itself and solves this issue:

```
function showHint(myId) 
{
    document.getElementById(myId).style.display = "inline" //@cc_on;
    + "-block";
}
```